# Is it possible to play FIFA 2015, 4v4 on 2 Consoles?

Tags: ps4, fifa-15

I've the following situation: My friends and I, we're 8 in total, want to play Fifa 15 4v4. I know that the Playstation 4 just supports 4 controllers and thats why we think about a 2 console + 2 TV's setup, so 4 players per console.

So my question is: Is it possible or is there a game mode available were we could play such a setup?

**Update:**
After I got the first answer I've to add that I know that the only way to play on 2 consoles would be through the psn online features. So we did not plan to play on Lan. We just want to sit in the same room with 2 consoles and play against each other over psn.

Comment: Other than the PS4 supporting 4 controllers, does FIFA 15 support 4 players on a single console as well? (Not sure myself) Just because the console supports it doesn't mean the game does also (it can support *up to* that amount of players, if the game devs choose to implement it)

Comment: yes fifa 15 supports 4 players local and up to 22 online see http://blog.hmv.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/FIFA-PS4.jpg

Answer (score -1):

FIFA, like 99% of console games, does not support LAN. So no, you can not do that. I don't know the game very well so I am assuming that you can't play online as a group of 4 otherwise you would have just done that.

Comment: I updated my question however nobody was talking about Lan.

Comment: If you weren't asking about LAN then how is this even an issue? I do not actually know how the online works in FIFA but since you play the game you should know... Can you play online as a group of 4? Either you should know or you should be able to just try it and find out. Can you invite another group to a game? Again you should either know or be able to just try and find out. If the question wasn't about LAN then I don't really understand why you bothered to ask it.

Comment: The problem here is, that i would need exactly the same setup and atm i haven't 2 consoles and 8 ppl at my home. However it is possible to play 2v2 on 2 consoles the mode is called co-op seasons but i dont know if it's possible to play 4v4 too thats why I ask. Btw nobody was talking about an issue.

Comment: You don't need another console to attempt to go online with your console and a group of 4... If it doesn't work then clearly you can't do it.