# 4v4 Fifa with two PS4's?

Tags: ps4, fifa-14, fifa-15

It's my friends stag weekend this weekend, and he loves Fifa.

Between us, we have 2x PS4's and 8 controllers.  I know on one PS4 you can do 4 player, just wondering if we're able to do 4v4 with two PS4's, either by connecting them somehow or by playing online?

Comment: possible dublicate? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/215539/is-it-possible-to-play-fifa-2015-4v4-on-2-consoles

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can directly connect them or anything like that but if fifa lets multiple people play online together (such as cod splitscreen online) then it could work if you press play with friends and have all of them sign in on the consols equally